# Clone a entire Document/Excel/Presentation on specific Version

Tags: onlyoffice

Is There any Options to Clone a Word / Excel / Presentation Based on document version number

```
for Ex:
  version - 4
  version - 3
  version - 2
  version - 1
```

Here I need to clone Version 4 In Onlyoffice Document Integration Server
and without any mismatch of editor contents

[image]

here I uploaded the image in that 7 version are there, I need to clone a 4'th version (which means version 4,3,2,1 and I don't want 5,6,7)  it's not like rollback, original document should not get change while cloning.

Answer (score -1):

Please describe the case more detailed, we need more information about the whole process, i.e. are you going to just copy the file or start a new conversion process?
Could you please specify if the versioning already works in your environment.
If yes, how is it organized.